# The concept of hole

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I read in Ashcroft solid state physics when talking about holes he wrote that

\begin{gather} j=+e\int_{unocupied}^{}\frac{dk}{4\pi^{3}}v(k) \end{gather}

and we can consider the current is due to positive charged particles filling up the unocuupied states and consider all other states being neutral

by that that the only reason I KNOW for treating holes as positive charged particles (due to the transport properties ).

but also I know that the holes are considered positive charged particles even if there is no transport at all .

so my question how to think about holes in a general way? and the reasons for thinking about them like that ? even if there is transport or not .

Comment: "In general" you won't be thinking about these concepts at all, but you will do a complete multi-quantum calculation, but for most applications in solid state and semiconductor physics that's way too much effort since we aren't interested in the complete state of the system (like the chemical lattice binding energies etc.) but only in charge transport. The electron/hole model is a semi-classical approximation that works remarkably well for that purpose, within reason. Holes, for instance, do not have the same diffusion constants as electrons, so it's not "just a charge" difference.

Comment: So you say that the concept of hole is just introduced for modeling the charge transport in the semiconductor?

Comment: When an electron is kicked from the inside of the Fermi surface to the outside, that creates an electron-hole pair; simply put, an unoccupied state below the Fermi surface behaves like the "positron" which basically termed a hole. Together with electrons, it is known as "electron-hole excitations."

Comment: It has more uses than that, I would say. It also models interaction with radiation like light reasonably well, for instance, but I would say affirmatively that it is a good model for limited purposes. By "good" I mean that it uses very few assumptions and the mathematics of the model is fairly simple while still returning qualitative and sufficiently quantitative results.

Comment: If you don’t treat holes and electrons as equals, semiconductor device physics will not go well for you.

Comment: @JonCuster ,My question is what is holes ? And how should we treat them ?

Comment: have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/intrin.html

Comment: @FlatterMann Nobody will ever do a "complete multi-quantum calculation" of the operation of a transistor. And what's "complete", anyway? More elaborate models are still approximations. The best you can ever have in physics is a useful, effective, approximate model.

Comment: @JohnDoty That was my point. In physics we are using models that are sufficient for the purpose we are trying to achieve. The electron/hole mode seems sufficient for charge transport in semiconductors the thermodynamic limit. It does, for instance, not describe the superconducting phase of matter. It does not give the correct expression for heat capacity at low temperatures etc.. For that we need other approximations. If we wanted to have a "ToE of the (semi)conductor", then we would have to do a multi-quantum  calculation, which nobody does.

Comment: @FlatterMann History suggests that we will never have a testable ToE. As theory gets more mathematically sophisticated, it gets more remote from reality. So, every useful, verified theory is an approximation.

Comment: @JohnDoty No argument there. The least useful theory of all is the ToE. I still don't know why so many people are obsessed with it. Who in their right mind needs quantum gravity to explain why the sandwich always lands on the peanut butter side?

Comment: A hole is an unoccupied state below the Fermi level. They occur in all different types of materials. In semiconductors they are very important because of detailed balance leading to equilibrium charge concentrations.

Comment: @JonCuster, what makes the hole positively charged? I know a reason that say , when calculating the current due to the electron in the valence band we find it equal to \begin{gather} j=+e\int_{unocupied}^{}\frac{dk}{4\pi^{3}}v(k) \end{gather} , from that we say that the unoccupied states can model the whole band provided that it has positive charge, is that the only reason or there is another one?

Comment: Free electron from the conduction band plus hole in the valence band makes nothing. So, the hole is positively charged.

Comment: @JonCuster, Should it be the free electron in conduction band and unbalanced proton in the atom ? When the atom lose electron it has an excess of protons inside it that what makes the balance

Comment: Electrons and holes both live in the electronic band structure, which are extended states not tied to any given atom.

Comment: @JonCuster 
I mean what balance the excess charge is the ion that created when an electron leave the valence band .

Comment: In solid state physics, all the atoms are background ions that the electronic structure is built upon. You can't tie electrons or holes to any given ion.

Comment: @JonCuster ,Can you clarify more ,my question is if an atom loses an electron,this atom get ionized by positive charge and that what balance the charge, which is the electron and the ionized atom. Then what gives positive charge to hole ?